# Counting Columns in ColdFusion's QoQ

Tags: oracle11g, coldfusion-10

I have:

```
 <cfspreadsheet action="read" src="#Trim(PathToExcelFile)#" query="Data">
```

How do I count the total column in my "Data" query using ColdFusion Query of Query? I need to count whether my users has used the corrent excel file format before inserting into my DB.
I'm using Oracle 11g and I can not do:

```
Select * From Data Where rownum < 2
```

If I can do that then I can create an array and count the columns but running that script using  results in error. The error saying that there is no column name Rownum. Oracle does not allow me to use select top 1.
I don't want to loop over 5000+ record to just count the total column of one row. I appreciate any help, thank you

Comment: *I'm using Oracle 11g* Makes no difference with a QoQ. They are done in memory and have no connection to your DBMS. QoQ's use a special dialect of SQL and only support [a few SQL functions](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/accessing-and-using-data/using-query-of-queries/query-of-queries-user-guide.html). Miguel-F's answer is definitely the correct approach for this task. However, FWIW the db-agnostic method of returning zero records is to tack on a filter that is never true, like `WHERE 1 = 0`.

Answer (score 2):

ColdFusion adds a few additional variables to it's query results. One of them is named `columnList' and contains a comma-separated list of the query columns that were returned.

[From the documentation here](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfquery.html)

From that you should be able to count the number of columns easily. `#listlen(Data.columnList)#` as one example.